# improve the performance of making slide video using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg

I have 10 images(1080x1920) and 2 video(1080x1920).
I want to merge all of them to make a final video using command:

```
INPUT_DATA=(_img1.jpg vid1.mp4 _img2.jpg vid2.mp4 _img3.jpg _img4.jpg _img5.jpg _img6.jpg _img7.jpg _img8.jpg _img9.jpg _img10.jpg)
IMAGE_TIME_SPAN=5
INPUT_DIR="input"
OUTPUT_DIR="output"
BACKGROUND_MUSIC="$INPUT_DIR/background.mp3"
OUTPUT_STEP1="$OUTPUT_DIR/tmp_video.mp4"
OUTPUT_STEP3="$OUTPUT_DIR/tmp_background.mp3"
OUTPUT_FILE="$OUTPUT_DIR/final.mp4"
SCALE_SIZE="1080x1920"

ffmpeg -y \
    -f lavfi -t 1 -i anullsrc \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[0]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[1]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[2]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[3]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[4]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[5]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[6]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[7]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[8]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[9]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[10]} \
    -i $INPUT_DIR/${INPUT_DATA[11]} \
    -filter_complex \
    "[1:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img1]; \
     [2:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,scale=$SCALE_SIZE[v1]; \
     [3:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img2]; \
     [4:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,scale=$SCALE_SIZE[v2]; \
     [5:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img3]; \
     [6:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img4]; \
     [7:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img5]; \
     [8:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img6]; \
     [9:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img7]; \
     [10:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img8]; \
     [11:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img9]; \
     [12:v]fade=t=in:st=0:d=4:alpha=1,zoompan=z='zoom+0.0009':d=25*$IMAGE_TIME_SPAN:s=$SCALE_SIZE[img10]; \
     [img1][0:a][v1][0:a][img2][0:a][v2][0:a][img3][0:a][img4][0:a][img5][0:a][img6][0:a][img7][0:a][img8][0:a][img9][0:a][img10][0:a]concat=n=12:v=1:a=1" \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:v libx264 \
    $OUTPUT_STEP1
```

I run this command on a virtual machine (Linux, 4GB memories) and it takes ~11 min to finish! It takes too long and I want to reduce the process time to less than 5 min.

Any suggestion for the better performance.

Comment: You can set a faster preset `-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast`

Comment: I set the preset to `ultrafast` and the process time reduces to less than 1 min. Thank you very much!!